# Regex replace(/\n/g, "<br />") doesn't work

Tags: jquery, regex

I have this string `02/11/2015 \n € \n` that I show into a popup. Before I do this I use a RegEx to replace `\n` with `<br/>`. But it doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
message= "02/11/2015 \n € \n";
message= message.replace(/\n/g, "<br />");

var popup = $('<div><span style="font-weight: bold; color: #1d5987;"> <p>'+ message+'</p> </span></div>');
$('document').append(popup);
popup.dialog({
    autoOpen : true,
    modal : true,
    resizable: false,
    width:'45%',
    height: 'auto',
    close: function(event, ui){ 
        $(this).dialog('destroy');
    }           
});
```

In the pop-up `02/11/2015 \n € \n` appears again.

I use the chrome console to debug it, after replace function is executed in the message string there are no changes.

Comment: `message= message.replace(/\n/g, "<br />");` It does replaces `\n` see http://jsfiddle.net/a5xn49hv/

Comment: Do you have literal `\n`s? Then use `/\\n/g`. Or if you have a mix of them, `/\\n|\n/g`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g3xn3jLt/)

You may have error in

```
$('document').append(popup);
```

The selector `'document'` is nothing. Use `$(document)` without the quotes, or rather `$('body')` or append directly to some element by ID